# how can i remove weird links from my website

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, google-search

i have a website that was developed with wordpress

it was hacked  ,I removed the malicious files that I've found on the server

and I got it back but when I search the website on google I found

strange links  that I can't  open them 
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uftNx.jpg)

Comment: Recrawl them on webmaster tools

Comment: thank you for your reply @charankumar , i did that but it does not worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove url individually form google webmaster tools and it will take time remove it.

Comment: thank you @Tawhidul Islam   i tried your solution but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You should know that removing malicious files doesn't mean you cleaned up the site. There are many instances where a file will recreate all the malicious files again. Sometimes it can even be above the root of your website root folder. It's best to use a couple plugins to scan the whole site directory. And then check a couple days later if the malicious files return. (if this is the case you are best to actually just switch to a new server or reformat if you have the option as it will get quite expensive to pay someone to clean up your server)

First make sure you have completely cleaned up the hack. Then those pages in Google should get deindex as they won't exist anymore. It's probably not viable to remove every single hack page indexed in Google via webmaster tools as there could be 10s of thousands! (depending on the hack)

Below are a couple good scanners.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/quttera-web-malware-scanner

https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner

I would also recommend some plugins for enhanced security moving forward.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninjafirewall

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security

https://wordpress.org/plugins/vulnerable-plugin-checker